# How to show user is online using Chatter Application MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am Creating MVC application chatter Application. I want show who is online in chatter. How can i show it?

I have chatter controller Code:

```
public ActionResult ChatterList(int ProjectId)
{
    ReadCookieValue cookie = new ReadCookieValue();
    clientId = cookie.readuserinfo().ClientId;
    userId = cookie.readuserinfo().Id;
    roleId = cookie.readuserinfo().RoleId;
    ChatterViewModel model = new ChatterViewModel();
    model.chattersList = Task.Run(() => _project.GetChatterList(ProjectId)).Result;
    foreach (var item in model.chattersList)
    {
        item.CurrentUserId = userId;
    }
    model.newChatter = new ChatterModel();
    model.newChatter.ProjectId = ProjectId;
    model.newChatter.UserId = userId;
    model.newChatter.UserName = cookie.readuserinfo().UserName;
    return View("ProjectChatter", model);
}

public async Task<ActionResult> AddChatter(ChatterViewModel model)
{
    if (model != null)
    {
        var obj = await _project.AddChatterList(model);
        if (model.newChatter.ProjectId == 3)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("EbitDaReports");
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Reports");
}
```

and i  created chatter using Project ID  view Code looks like

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="ibox-content">
        <div class="chat-discussion">

            <div class="ibox float-e-margins">




                <div class="chat-element right">
                    <div class="row m-t-lg">

                        @if (Model.ProjectId > 0)
                        {
                            @Html.Action("ChatterList", "Projects", new { @ProjectId = Model.ProjectId })
                        }
                    </div>

                </div>



            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying To use

```
<div class="row">
    @if (HttpRuntime.Cache["ProjectId"] != null)
    {
        var loggedOnUsers = HttpRuntime.Cache["ProjectId"] as Dictionary<string, DateTime>;

        if (loggedOnUsers != null)
        {<div class="ProjectId">
        }
        <span> Online Users: </span>
    </div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

I am getting Nothing. i need to create new controller ? or else i can override existing controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the dictionary items and display that.

```
<div class="row">
    @if (HttpRuntime.Cache["ProjectId"] != null)
    {
        var loggedOnUsers = HttpRuntime.Cache["ProjectId"] as Dictionary<string, DateTime>;
        <span> Online Users: </span>
        if (loggedOnUsers != null)
        {
            foreach (var userItem in loggedOnUsers.Keys)
            {
                <p>@userItem <span>@loggedOnUsers[userItem]</span></p>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <p>No users!</p>
        }

    }
    else
    {
      <h2>Could not find a HttpRuntime Cache entry with key "ProjectId"</h2>
    }
</div>
```

This will list the users and their time assuming that `HttpRuntime.Cache["ProjectId"]` stores a dictionary of string & date time for the online users.

**EDIT :** *Showing sample code how to set data to the Cache.*

This is how you add item to the Cache, You need to execute code like this somewhere in your app ( may be when user logs to chat, add a new entry).

```
var data = HttpRuntime.Cache["ProjectId"] as Dictionary<string, DateTime>;
if(data==null)
    data=new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
data.Add("Scott",DateTime.Now);
data.Add("Shyju", DateTime.Now);
data.Add("Kevin", DateTime.Now);
HttpRuntime.Cache["ProjectId"] = data;
```

Comment: still i am getting blank page @Shyju

Comment: Do you have this code in your view? Do you see any messages ( "No users" ?). What you mean blank page  ? Complete blank page ? Nothing in that? You may have some other error in your page then. I suggest you remove all code and just put this and see what happens

Comment: i have tired  remove all  code put this code i am getting blank page

Comment: i need to mention  HttpRuntime.Cache["ProjectId"]  in my controller ?

Comment: Ofcourse you need to have data in that ! Why would you try to query that if you do not have data. See the last sentence from my answer. I also updated the answer to show a message when you do not have that item in Cache. Try that.

Comment: i will check  @Shyju

Comment: I am getting now Could not find a HttpRuntime Cache entry with key "ProjectId" @shyju

Comment: There you go. As i mentioned multiple times earlier, you need to set the Cache items. I updated the answer with sample code. You need to execute the code somewhere in your app

Comment: thank you @shyju  i  run your code i got answer  but when i add data.Add("ProjectID",datatime) i am getting   Online Users:
ProjectId 8/3/2016 8:03:40 PM

Comment: Because you are adding the key as "ProjectID", Replace it with a name

Comment: Name means i need to add  user login name  default ? @shyju  please explain little more

Comment: Yes.When a user logs in to your chat system, you need to add an dictionary entry with his name and current time.

Comment: I have user In my Site login  four users now i added                                                                              data.Add("Vignesh Ramachandran", DateTime.Now);
            data.Add("Sree Vatsan", DateTime.Now);
            data.Add("Sudharshan", DateTime.Now);
            data.Add("Ed Applegate", DateTime.Now);
 
            HttpRuntime.Cache["ProjectId"] = data;   and run the code i showing four user online users but  now chat session one user now online